# Fabric Crashlytics Android events sending

Tags: android, google-fabric

I'm using Fabric Crashlytics for Android and it's really a great engine, and notifies me whenever there's a crash (on both the dashboard and my emai), but what i want to know is that:

Can I send an event to the dashboard (or my email) when the app catches an exception (i.e can i send the `exception.printStackTrace()` whenever the app catches an exception)?

Comment: Show your coding Snapshot.

Comment: there's no code snapshot, i only added what they said and it's working, i'm just asking if this feature is availabl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.

https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    Crashlytics.logException(e);
    // handle your exception here!
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to log details of the error, see fabric [doc](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html)

```
try
{
   // your code
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   Crashlytics.logException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found it, we can log the catched exceptions
HERE IT IS
https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html